# ios11:in-house app does not display icons and does not display progress

Tags: ios, ios11, enterprise

When downloading and installing the enterprise application on iOS11, the icon is not displayed for the blank, the state is waiting, but it is actually downloaded and downloaded after the normal display and use.
IOS10 and previous versions have not appeared before. There will normally be downloading progress and icons. Plist has not been modified. I don't know what the new feature of iOS11 is or bug. I always think it's a network problem.
Only recently did I test other old iOS before I found normal. Only iOS11 has this problem. I found many, did not find the answer, estimated business account number is also less.
[app installing screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T65sG.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://xx.com/kmia_ump.ipa</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://xx.com/180.png</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://xx.com/1024.png</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>xx.xx.xxxx</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>xxx</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>xxx</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: i edit it ,and add my plist file.thinks

Comment: edit again and fix it